# How do you modify a data of all authenticated users at a go in firebase database

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my current application users get authenticated and signin and they have a particular child inside them which is a push id(Unique id)... i want to change all the pushid's data at one go of a particular user... is that possible?

**Database** 
[image]

As you can see i have a user's unique id and inside that another users id and inside that are push ids created... so at one go i want to change a particular data inside all the push ids of a user... How can i do that... please help

Comment: Post the code what you have tried regarding that @Emilia James ?

Comment: i'm not able to access the push ids... thats the problem @Raj

Comment: You can not update pushids but you can change values of child of push-id. Show what code you've written already. Make firebase reference to the user-id, and use firebase update method to update the child values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Query q;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    q =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Messages").child("id1").child("id2").orderByChild("Seen").equalTo(0);
    q.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnaphot.getChildren()) {
                ds.getRef().child("Seen").setValue(1);
            }
        } 

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }   
    });
}
```

Here i updating the Seen value to 1 whose Seen values were 0 before. I hope this will work for you.